# Display html page content before reboot

Tags: raspbian, php, lighttpd

I have a raspberry with lighttpd and php. Now I want to display webpage content before the raspberry is rebooting when I click on a link. I have create the page below. But when I load the page it isn’t display the content but it is direct rebooting.

```
 <?php 
   echo "<html>";
   echo "<head>";
   echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"15; url=rebooted.html\">";
   echo "</head>";
   echo "<body>";
   echo "<p><b>The device is restarting now. Please wait.</b><p>";
   echo "</body>";
   echo "</html>";

   flush();
   system('sudo /sbin/reboot');
 ?>
```

Anyone any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. As soon as your Linux system starts a reboot then no new process can be instantiated.

`sudo reboot` is almost instantaneous.

Also allowing a PHP program running as user=www-data group=www-data is a security exposure if it can run any process with `sudo`.

Comment: Yes I know it is a security exposure . But that is a choice that I have made

Comment: Actually new processes can easily be instantiated, unless you are doing `reboot -f`, which you should not normally do.  But that isn't the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, while `flush();` tells it to send, it doesn't actually finish sending instantaneously.  If you put a `sleep(0.5);` after the flush, there is a much better chance of finishing.

A better solution might be to write a program to use in place of `sudo reboot` that closes its input and output, sleeps half a second, and invokes the `sudo reboot`.  This will allow the web page output to actually finish before the reboot starts.  Perhaps something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<1024; i++) close(i);
    open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
    open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
    open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
    usleep(500000);
    /* system("/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot"); */
    execl("/usr/bin/sudo", "sudo", "/sbin/reboot", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this do the job ?

`sudo shutdown -r -t 5`

Reboot after a delay of 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. I solved it with:

```
 exec("sudo reboot > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
 flush();
 exit;
```